# how to open application when i click on it in launcher app android

Tags: android, facebook, android-launcher

i working on launcher app and want to know how to launch application like Facebook app when i click on it from the home screen of the launcher

i tried this code but its open all the package from the store directly , and i want this click open or launch the application from the device  directly

```
    Button facebook= (Button) findViewById(R.id.facebook);
    facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        final String appPackageName = "com.facebook.katana"; 
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));

    }
    });

     }
```

so is there is another way to launch it directly from the device ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a custom launcher I would expect that you are programatically establishing which applications are already installed on the device using [PackageManager's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) methods, but from your sample it appears you are assuming Facebook is already installed.

Anyway, you can use [PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29):

```
        Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana");
        startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Note that getLaunchIntent will throw NameNotFoundException if Facebook is not installed, so you should make the display of the icon conditional on Facebook being installed. It will return null if there is no launch intent for the package too, so you should guard against that as well.